# npm install errors on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am self-learning Angular and was trying to run this project: https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin

I downloaded the zip file and did `npm install` in VSCode's Terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) and my Node and NPM versions are:

```
ajay@linuxpc:~/Documents$ node -v
v16.13.2
ajay@linuxpc:~/Documents$ npm --version
8.3.1
```

I am getting errors as:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.2' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.2"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:26979) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ajay/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ajay/.node-gyp/16.13.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ajay/.node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /home/ajay/.node-gyp/16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ajay/Documents/ngx-admin-master/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ajay/.npm/_logs/2022-01-24T15_26_04_273Z-debug-0.log
```

I dont think (and assuming) there will be some error in the project as its a big open source project and should run without any such errors as above.

There must be something horribly wrong at my end. Where should I start debugging for these errors?

**Update:**
I also tried `sudo apt install make gcc build-essential` but that also didn't help.

Comment: You need the angular-cli to run angular apps. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you try to download and install Node.js from the bellow link.
  https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.15.0/
- Then to confirm check with node -v.
- Then sudo apt install npm

Do not install node v 16. Try to install Node.js v14.15.0.